# Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-delete, delimiter, beforeupdate

```
 Delimiter$$
 create trigger salary_delete
 before delete
 on salary
 for each row begin
 insert into salary_dele(eid,validfrom,amount)
 value(old.eid,old.validfrom,old.amount);
 end if;
 end$$
 delimeter;
```

UNABLE TO FIND THE MISTAKE .PLEASE HELP

Comment: There is no IF to match the end if;?

Comment: Change `delimeter;`  to  `delimiter;` and remove end if as previous comment mentioned https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6LMbhugzVigtcxJzVkCVLs/0 . Please check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html for more details

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```sql
create trigger salary_delete
 before delete
 on salary
 for each row 
 insert into salary_dele(eid,validfrom,amount)
 value(old.eid,old.validfrom,old.amount);
```

Single-statement compound statement does not need in BEGIN-END and DELIMITER.